# Return pointer from function to main

Tags: pointers, null

I want to return a pointer value to my main function but it works only locally and the value of root = NULL remains the same outside the function insert.

```
   node *insert(int number,   node *root ){



        if(root==NULL){
            root = new node;
            root->key = number;
            printf("%d", number);
            return root;
        } }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it works only locally*? How do you call this function?

Comment: insert(number,root); inside the function the root = new node but when I add insert(number,root,current);
    printf("%d",root); the root is still NULL but I have declared that root = new node;

Answer (score 0):

The parameter variables are actually stack variables which are initialized by the caller of the function.

When you assign "root= new node;" you are doing it to the local "root"

How do you call insert() from main()?
You can:

```
node* newRoot = insert(x, oldRoot);
```

Than the "new node" will be assigned to newRoot. You can even:

```
oldRoot= insert(x, oldRoot);
```

Than the "new node" will be assigned to oldRoot

But you will have troubles deleting all these later on...

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the `root` is being *returned*, so in `main()` you should call it like this:

```
node *root = insert(4711, nullptr);
```

I used `nullptr` since this is clearly C++ and I believe that's how it's supposed to be spelled today.